# Using `$mdToast` inside an interceptor triggering circular dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, circular-dependency, angular-http-interceptors, angularjs-material

**Question:**

How can I use `$mdToast` inside an interceptor without triggering the error?

**Setup:**

**Interceptor definition:**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.components.http-errors-interceptors')
    .factory('HttpError500Interceptor', HttpError500Interceptor);

  /* @ngInject */
  function HttpError500Interceptor($q,
                                   $mdToast,
                                   $filter) {

    var interceptor           = {};
    interceptor.responseError = responseError;

    function responseError(responseError) {
      if (responseError.status === 500) {
        $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple()
                              .content($filter('translate')('APP.COMPONENTS.HTTP_ERRORS_INTERCEPTORS.500'))
                              .position('bottom right')
                              .hideDelay(5000));
      }
      return $q.reject(responseError);
    }

    return interceptor;
  }
})();
```

**Interceptor config:**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.components.http-errors-interceptors')
    .config(moduleConfig);

  /* @ngInject */
  function moduleConfig($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpError500Interceptor');
  }
})();
```

**Issue:**

When I load the application it triggers the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <-
>   $templateRequest <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- $$interimElement <-
>   $mdToast <- HttpError500Interceptor <- $http <- $templateFactory <-
>   $view <- $state

Comment: didi you find the fix?

Comment: @KumarSambhav Yes, I was able to workaround this, see my answer below to fit your specific use-case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of the provided solutions worked for me, so I'm posting here what I did so anyone with the same issue can have a range of workarounds to use.

What I really wanted was to have a common component to handle HTTP interceptors named `interceptors` and show the messages directly from the module, and happily, since the final solution is more elegant, it triggered this error while injecting the `$mdToast` service.

The solution I came later, which I already said, is more elegant that my first fix to the issue is:

- to have a common component to handle HTTP interceptors named `interceptors`,
- to have a common component to handle global notifications named `notifications-hub`.

Then, in the `interceptors` module, I trigger a global event with:

`$rootScope.$broadcast('notifications:httpError', responseError);`

Then, in the `notifications-hub` module, I registered on the event and used the `$mdToast`, which was injected without errors in the notifications service:

`$rootScope.$on('notifications:httpError', function (event, responseError) {
    NotificationsHubService.processErrorsAndShowToast(responseError);
});`

`NotificationsHubService` is the service injecting `$mdToast`.

**Conclusion:**

I used a global event as a glue between the low-level interceptors and the notifications subsystem to overcome the issue.

Hopefully it will be of use for anyone else.

Comment: It really seems a much more correct and elegant solution, according to the principles of single responsibility.

Answer (score 5):

One work around that has helped me in the past is to use `$injector` to get your dependency at runtime instead of at configuration time. So, something like:

```
  /* @ngInject */
  function HttpError500Interceptor($q,
                                   $injector,
                                   $filter) {
    function responseError(responseError) {
      var $mdToast = $injector.get('$mdToast');
```

When your cyclic dependency does not cause problems, which it probably doesn't in this case, this will do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I already tried that with no use, the same error is triggered. Any other thoughts? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Mmm. I can't explain that. This should break the dependency chain. Are you sure it is the exact same error?

Comment: Yeah: ```Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- $templateRequest <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- $$interimElement <- $mdToast <- HttpError500Interceptor <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state```

Comment: How can `$mdToast <- HttpError500Interceptor` when you actually remove that dependency and get it at runtime? The `$injector.get` call does not add the dependency. Perhaps have a look if that `@ngInject` is not generating that dependency.

Comment: Well, I reported this issue to angular-material devs at github. It seems a bug to me since is illogical that the service to show notifications to users (`$mdToast`) can't be used in interceptors which mainly are used for this reason (400 or 500 errors interceptors). For future reference: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6946

Comment: Perhaps you can put the get call in a setTimeout of duration 0

Comment: Tried that after your suggestion and nothing, the same error. Don't worry, the angular-material dev that responded me in github said that this seems as an edge case bug, so they will look upon this. In the meantime, I will duplicate the modal call in every promise that fails as a catch. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Don't put this line `var $mdToast = $injector.get('$mdToast');` immediately inside the interceptor function. Put it inside the `responseError` function, so it won't cause circular dependency error.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is create a function that brings you the toaster at run time

```
  var getToaster = ()=>{

    var toaster = $injector.get('$mdToaster');
    return toaster;
}
```

Now call it only when you need it  - this will provide a work around the dependency circular

Comment: That didn't worked, see previous comments. It is an edge case bug found in the recents version. See https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6946